# Category containing its own morphisms as objects

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to construct a language the objects of which are some objects and morphisms between own objects. Not sure even if this construction is a category. Is there any name of this kind of structures?

---

**
Actually let me add more details: Assume we have two basic objects in category. The objects are $A$ and $B$ and there is a single morphism between them $f: A \rightarrow B$. Then the category should include the $f$ as an object. So we may have another morphism $g: f \rightarrow A$ and in this case $g$ is also an object etc.

---

And I am also trying to prove that this structure is not a category. It is also appreciated if one can prove that this is not a category.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking for, but maybe [slice categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Slice_category) are what you are looking for. The objects of a slice category $(c \downarrow C)$ are paris $(a,f)$ where $a \in C$ and $f: c \rightarrow a$ and a morphism $h: (a,f) \rightarrow (b,g)$ is a morphism $h: a \rightarrow b$ s.t. $h \circ f = g$.

Comment: @G.Chiusole excellent suggestion. My first idea is that this is about [arrow categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category), where the objects of the underlying category would be identified with the identity morphisms.

Comment: I have added some additional info to the question. The slice category seems something similar but  not exactly what I am looking for. Actually the construction I have in mind seems is not a category. I am just trying to fit it under some category.

Comment: The category of sets seems to do this.

Comment: Thanks @jgon If I choose one basic object (only $\emptyset$) and trivial morphism ($I \rightarrow \emptyset : \emptyset$) then this construction will be equivalent to category of sets, that is true. But what if I choose 2 or more basic objects? Will it still remain category and will this category be the category of sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be clear that I don't think what you're trying to construct is a category. However, I'll do my best to give a categorical interpretation of what you've put in the question.

Let me be clear that in a category, morphisms are *themselves* objects only by coincidence. I.e., for a morphism $f: A\to B$, the existence of an object of the category $O$ with $O=f$ mathematically is a coincidence. This property, while true for the standard constructions of some categories, like $\newcommand\Set{\mathbf{Set}}\Set$ is a coincidence in the sense that this property is not preserved under equivalence or even isomorphism of categories. We can always replace a category by an isomorphic category whose set of objects and morphisms are disjoint.

Moreover, without specifying something further, you get very little useful information about the category, since we have no idea what the arrows into or out of the object $O=f$ are, and they don't necessarily have any relation to $f$.

**A categorical interpretation**

If you want to categorify the observation that in $\Set$ every arrow is itself an object, since we define functions $f:X\to Y$ by their graph $G_f \subseteq X\times Y$, then we can categorify the notion of the *graph* of a morphism.

If $f:X\to Y$, then I would define a graph of $f$, $G_f$ if it exists to be a subobject 
$\iota : G_f\hookrightarrow X\times Y$ such that $\pi_1 \iota : G_f\to X$ is an isomorphism and $\pi_2(\pi_1\iota)^{-1} = f$.

Graphs exist in a lot of categories. They exist in toposes, or in categories of algebraic objects, as well as in lots of geometric categories.

Comment: I understand your point here. So may I rephrase that the objects in category are "similar" objects, while morphisms and objects are different by definition. In a set theory there is a special isomorphisms between the functions and sets, so we use this isomorph set to represent a function as a set. And accordingly we have the morphisms represented as a sets. Could you please confirm?

Comment: And also thank you for entering to this topic so deep. I need to create a software which has an underneath structure like the one I have described. I need some proof that this is relevant structure and can be represented as some math structure. So I am trying to find that structure.

Answer (score 4):

What are the "objects of a language"? The entities its first-order quantifiers run over? [That's the usual story!]

Category theory is usually set up with a *two-sorted* first order language with objects and morphisms as distinct sorts. But it would only be mildly perverse to take the official language of category theory to be single-sorted, with quantifiers running over entities comprising the category's objects *and* the morphisms (then restricting quantifiers when you want to talk about just the objects, or just the morphisms).

In this single-sorted version, the objects in the single domain of the language will include morphisms between [some of] the domain's own objects.

Presumably, though, you are not interested in this triviality! So I guess the question needs to be refined to give us something clearer to grapple with (so we know whether slice or arrow categories are relevant to real your concerns, for example.)

Comment: Thanks, I have added some additional information to the question. Actually the slice category is something that looks similar. But I have added more details to the question and from there one can see that the required structure is not exactly that category and even may be not a category. But I can not proof that  this is not a category.